# How to install Bumblebee on Debian 8 (nvidia proprietary drivers) - package not found

Tags: debian, apt

I followed this guide: https://wiki.debian.org/Bumblebee#Installation

but when I run

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee-nvidia primus
```

this is the output:

```
....
Package bumblebee-nvidia is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'bumblebee-nvidia' has no installation candidate
```

Perhaps it's because as the guides says I should...

> requires contrib and non-free enabled in your sources.list

However I don't understand **how** to do it.

Also, what does **but is referred to by another package** mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bumblebee-nvidia` is indeed in `contrib`; to add `contrib` and `non-free`, you need to edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, and add `contrib non-free` at the end of lines starting with `deb`. You'll end up with something like

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
```

etc. (the URL will probably be different, and you may have something other than `stable`; keep the values in your file). (Copy your original `sources.list` file somewhere safe beforehand...)

Once that's done,

```
apt-get update
```

as `root`, then you should be able to install `bumblebee-nvidia`.

"referred to by another package" means that `bumblebee-nvidia` is mentioned in the information of some package your system already knows about; in this case `bumblebee` which is in `main`.